# Replacing characters through a middle man

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function where the first and second arguments entered are a character vectors. The first set of characters is a coded message. The second argument is a key. These two arguments are related through a set character list. I want to read the message, relate the character to the list, and then have the list equal to the key. Then print the message out. For example:

```
message <- c(d, b, c, c, a)

list <- c(letters)

key <- c(o, e, l, l, h)

message: d, b, c, c, a

list: a, b, c, d         
 key: o, e, l, h
```

So looking at the message the first character is "d" which when you go down to list and find "d" it matches with "h". If you continue this for all the letters the decoded message is: "hello".

I have had multiple ideas as to how to do this, but being a new R user I'm not sure which way may even work.

Currently, this is what I have so far:

```
decode.msg <- function(message, key){
i <- NULL
for(i in message) if(message[i]==list[i]){
      decode.msg <-(key[i, ]==list[i, ])
   }
}
```

Thoughts and ideas? Thanks for your time

Comment: For your example, just something like `key[order(message)]` will do the job

Answer (score 1):

This will probably be simpler using the `chartr` function:

```
> chartr( 'abcd','oelh', 'dbcca' )
[1] "hello"
> chartr( 'abcd','oelh', c('d','b','c','c','a') )
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"

> chartr( paste(letters[1:4], collapse=''),
+   paste( c('o','e','l','h'), collapse=''),
+   c('d','b','c','c','a') )
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It works except for a slight hiccup. I forgot to mention that the vectors in the variables are all spaced out. For example, message prints out to:

"d" "b" "c" "c" "a"

As a result, I'm getting back:
Warning messages:
1: In chartr(symbols, decode.key, coded.msg): argument 'old' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used 2: In chartr(symbols, decode.key, coded.msg): argument 'new' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used.
The message is printed but the substitutions aren't being made. Does the old and new need to be collapsed?

Comment: @Holder, yes the `old` and `new` arguments need to be collapsed.  See my 3rd example above (but you can use the name of the vector rather than the raw vector).